# How Kafka guarantees zero downtime and zero data loss?

Tags: apache-kafka

Gone through about Kafka. But don't know about how it achieves zero downtime and zero loss.

Comment: I've ran into multiple issues where data has been lost on highly replicated topics (more accurately, messages are skipped by a consumer). In other words, there's still bugs depending which version you're using and settings you're using

Answer (score 11):

I'll answer to your question by explaining how Kafka works in general and how it deals with failures.

Every *topic*, is a particular stream of data (similar to a table in a database). Topics, are split into *partitions* (as many as you like) where each message within a partition gets an incremental id, known as offset as shown below.

**Partition 0:**

```
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | ... |
+---+---+---+-----+
```

**Partition 1:**

```
+---+---+---+---+----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | .. |
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Now a Kafka cluster is composed of multiple *brokers*. Each broker is identified with an ID and can contain certain topic partitions.

Example of 2 topics (each having 3 and 2 partitions respectively):

**Broker 1:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 2       |
|   Partition 1     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 2:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 2    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 2       |
|   Partition 0     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 3:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 1    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Note that data is distributed (and *Broker 3* doesn't hold any data of *topic 2*).

Topics, should have a `replication-factor` > 1 (usually 2 or 3) so that when a broker is down, another one can serve the data of a topic. For instance, assume that we have a topic with 2 partitions with a `replication-factor` set to 2 as shown below:

**Broker 1:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 2:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 1       |
|   Partition 1     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 3:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 1    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Now assume that *Broker 2* has failed. *Broker 1* and 3 can still serve the data for topic 1. A `replication-factor` of 3 is always a good idea since it allows for one broker to be taken down for maintenance purposes and also for another one to be taken down unexpectedly.

That’s the general idea around how Kafka offers strong durability and fault tolerance guarantees.

**Note about Leaders:**
At any time, only one broker can be a leader of a partition and only that leader can receive and serve data for that partition. The remaining brokers will just synchronize the data (in-sync replicas). Also note that when the `replication-factor` is set to 1, the *leader* cannot be moved elsewhere when a broker fails. In general, when all replicas of a partition fail or go offline, the `leader` will automatically be set to `-1`.

Comment: how does kafka guarantee availability *while* the leader election is happening? Once a broker goes down, there'll be an intermittent period when no broker is the leader and election might be in place. What happens to produce/consume requests during that period?

Comment: In the `Broker 2` diagram on the bottom, you have Topic1/Partition 0 repeated twice. Did you mean to have Topic1/Partition0 and Topic1/Partition 1?