# what happen to the messages when connection is down between kafka server and producer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

i m new in kafka using spring boot and i m working in projet that i want to integrate kafka using spring into it ,
so the problem is i want to send message from the producer to the consumer even if **the kafka server don't running**(offline mode)

Can anyone give me example of how using kafka in offline mode ,
i can't find a tuto for this topic 
i want to stop my kafka server(for example) and in the same time producer want to send data to the topic,then the consumer can get these message?
what's the best solution?are they true ?

*sending data to a file, and when the server return to run (i test connexion for example),i export data from the file to the topic

*sending data to database and when the server return to run (test connexion),the same i send message(data) from database to my topic

*using a queue or a list to store message and when the server return to run (test connexion),i send data from the list to the topic but the problem that i have a lot of messages

-->if there are other solution with a simple example ,can anyone help me?

this is example of brocker **Redis** that we test the connection between Redis brocker and producer , if connection fails, i will store data inside a **Queue** which can store many messages, and when connection return to work between Redis and producer ,the producer now get these messages from the Queue and send them to the Redis Brocker .

But the problem in this brocker ,there are a few message lost
so we decide to integrate kafka brocker inside my project instead of Redis brocker!

Can anyone give me example in java how to store a lot of message before sending them by producer to kafka cluster?or what's the best solution to this problem  because we don't want to use the same Queue solution?

this example in python is how store message inside a Queue if connexion failed to the server:

```
    try:
    urllib.request.urlopen('http://serverAdress', timeout=0.1)
    r.publish(topicProduction,json_background_of_message1)
    print(json_background_of_message1)
    arretControle=Tru
    except Exception as e:
    qArret.put(json_background_of_message1)
    print("arret")
    arretControle=True
```

//json_background_of_message1 is the Queue that we can store a lot of messages in this Queue before sending these message if the connexion is failed

Comment: Kafka cluster should be running all the time. The few brokers can go down and cluster will work properly (depends on replication factor). There is not such thing like `using kafka in offline mode`.

Comment: if for example my producer want to send 1000 message and suddenly my remote **kafka** server is down (my application server is down suddenly)after sending 10 messsages by the producer !!!what happene for the 990 messages(the rest of messages)? Are there a solution to store these message or what should i do if my kafka server is down?

Comment: Kafka is running as a cluster, so even if one broker (_remote kafka server_) is down, you can send and consume messages. You have to set properly replication factor. I would suggest you go through Kafka Documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/). It is really good.

Comment: in the project which i work in ,the previous developer has integrated the **Redis** brocker into it and he has tested the connection between the redis and the producter
if there is a connection -> we can send producer messages to our brocker redis
otherwise we will store the messages sent by the producer in a Queue (in a list) and when the connexion back then the producer can sent messages ...but there are a lose message

Comment: thx  wardziniak for your help                                                                                          i do the same thing or what ? are you inderstand me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Kafka guarantees zero downtime and zero data loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227472/how-kafka-guarantees-zero-downtime-and-zero-data-loss)

Comment: Giorgos Myrianthous it's not the same problem ,please see the **Redis** example en python that i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka is designed to be a highly-available messaging system.  Configured correctly, and depending on the replication factor, you can have multiple brokers go down, completely, for days at a time, and the cluster would still work (albeit under higher load probably).  Every single Kafka production cluster I've worked with hasn't been completely down, ever, once it was successfully deployed.  We've had individual brokers go down, for days at a time sometimes, but that was never a problem.

What you're proposing is a fallback or backup method, in case Kafka is not available.  However, you still have the same problem.  If you dump messages to a file, how long until you run out of disk space?  If you store messages in a database, how long until the database runs out space?  If you store messages in an in-memory queue, how long until you run out of memory, and crashes the application?  And now you also have to build a mechanism to recover from a kafka outage, which adds complexity and overhead.

The best approach with Kafka is to configure it and handle it as a highly-available-system, configure alerts and metrics properly, so you'll be immediately alerted, and can react promptly, if something goes wrong.  Also, you should always size and test your applications so you have enough headroom to handle even your worst case scenario.  If you configure it to use replication factor 3, you would be able to lose any two brokers, and the cluster would still be able to function with no data loss.

Now, on the application side, your behavior in case Kafka is unavailable should depend on how important the messages are.  If you can tolerate losing messages, then just drop them if producer returns an exception, and log it/send an alert.  However, if they're extremely important records, then you shouldn't acknowledge/commit the messages on your upstream system (wherever the records originated from) until you have full confirmation that they're saved in Kafka.  I would recommend setting producer acks to `-1` or `all` for this, multiple retries in case of failure, and setting up a proper Callback method on the `producer.send()` method.  See here for much more detailed explanation: https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html

For more details, like others have said, please give the official docs a read:  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/